# How to post local image to user's friends wall using graph api, objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I've try so many time to figure it out but it still not working.

```
NSString *full = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"200" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:full];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               image,@"picture",
                               @"OK! I just trying to test",@"message",nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"My_Friend_ID/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

This code post only message on my friend wall not with the image, I also try with this:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"My_Friend_ID/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

This code dose post image on current user instead!

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I was unaware you can HTTP POST a photo directly to a friends stream or album.  However, you can for the current logged in user IF you have `publish_stream` permissions. Please note, a app user cannot grant you `friends_publish_stream` because that permissions just doesn't exist.

---

From the docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

**PHOTO connection of User**

**Create**

You can post photos to a user's Wall on their behalf by issuing an HTTP POST request to `PROFILE_ID/photos` with the `publish_stream` permissions and the following parameters.

---

And from albums docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

**PHOTOS connection of Album**

**Create**

You can add photos to an album by issuing an HTTP POST request to ALBUM_ID/photos with the publish_stream permissions and the following parameters.

---

Here's some examples for iOS on how to upload a photo from the phone to a user's wall or album.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/

http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/12/uploading-photos-to-facebook-in-corona/

Comment: Many thanks for you guys trying to help. U guys mention that Facebook dose not provide api for posting image on friend's wall or might not exist yet.

But why Facebook app can do that? Or Can I post image on a group or a page instead of friend's wall? Are there exist api for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set an image file as an argument for posting to another user's wall.  You can, however, post a link.
See Facebook's docs.  Check the section about a Post's fields:

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/](http://Graph%20API%3a%20Posts)

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Many thanks for you guys trying to help. U guys mention that Facebook dose not provide api for posting image on friend's wall or might not exist yet.

But why Facebook app can do that? Or Can I post image on a group or a page instead of friend's wall? Are there exist api for that?

Comment: You can post an image by providing a link to it.  You can't post an image file itself.